# Trying to get a property set based on a combobox selection in access 2010

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba, ms-access-2010

I thought I had it figured out but I'm trying to set the value of a field in my form based off of two combobox selections. The first few I tested worked out ok but when I added more I stopped getting results.

Snippet of code so far:

```
If (Product_Select = "Krystar 20kg") Then
    If (Batch_Number_Select = "Batch 1") Then
        DoCmd.SetProperty "Text5", , "60"
    ElseIf (Batch_Number_Select = "Batch 2") Then
        DoCmd.SetProperty "Text5", , "61"
    ElseIf (Batch_Number_Select = "Batch 3") Then
        DoCmd.SetProperty "Text5", , "62"
    ElseIf (Batch_Number_Select = "Batch 4") Then
        DoCmd.SetProperty "Text5", , "63"
    ElseIf (Batch_Number_Select = "Batch 5") Then
        DoCmd.SetProperty "Text5", , "64"
    End If
End If
```

Anyone see anything wrong? The syntax looks good to my eyes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use `DoCmd.SetProperty`, so I had to look it up. The default value for the second parameter is `acPropertyEnabled`, whereas it looks like you want to be setting it to `acPropertyValue`. Is there a reason `Me.Text5 = "60"` wouldn't work for you?